# conditional drop-down list on row cluster values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table:

[image: Table]

Is there a way to have dynamic drop-down list including all values from only same cluster (example of possible values in Link list column)? Cluster column is big so I am looking for dynamic solution.

Comment: Yes... where do you want the drop list to go?  In Column C (Link List) ?

Comment: Yes in Column C. Could you help please. So, drop down list will have possible values as in the "Link list" column.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this with formulas, but it's a bit involved. Bottom line is that here is the result I came up with:

[image]

The drop-down was created dynamically using dynamic named ranges and formulas

We need to start out with some definitions. This is my test worksheet and data:

[image]

The formulas will work out using the named ranges, so you can put your "working area" (the boxed area in green) almost anywhere, including on a different (possibly hidden) worksheet.

You must define four, dynamic named ranges as follows, which match the color-shaded areas in the image above:

[image]

Many of these formulas are [array formulas](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula), so you must be careful to enter them with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Once your data areas and names are defined, the first area to populate is the `UniqueClusterList` (the range on the sheet is `F2:M2`). We're building a list of unique items, based on the data in your column of cluster values. So you need an [array formula that identifies all the unique values in the range](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list). In each cell in the range, enter the ***array formula*** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> for each:

```
Cell F2    =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($E$2:E2,ClusterList)=0),ClusterList),"")
Cell G2    =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($E$2:F2,ClusterList)=0),ClusterList),"")
Cell H2    =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($E$2:G2,ClusterList)=0),ClusterList),"")
Cell I2    =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($E$2:H2,ClusterList)=0),ClusterList),"")
```

... and so on. Notice that only the cell address in the middle is changing.

Next, we need to build up the list of IDs for each unique Cluster value. This is also an array formula. Starting in cell `F3` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(IDList, SMALL(IF(F$2=ClusterList, ROW(IDList)-2,""), ROW()-2)),"")
```

Then use your cursor to grab the auto-fill icon in the selection box of that cell and drag it down to cell `F16`. Since cells `F3:F16` are now selected, re-grab the auto-fill icon and drag to the right to fill the whole range `F2:M16`. All of the values should pop-in as calculated by the formulas.

Your final step is to create the lookup formula for the drop-down list. So select cell `C3`, then on the ribbon click *Data --> Data Tools --> Data Validation* to get the dialog window. Now select *Allow: **List***, and in the *Source:* field enter the following formula:

```
 =OFFSET($F$2,1,MATCH(A3,UniqueClusterList,0)-1,SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(IDList,OFFSET($F$2,0,MATCH(A3,UniqueClusterList,0)-1,MAXUNIQUE,1))),1)
```

[image]

You'll now have a drop-down in cell `C3` that matches the very first image above. Drag the auto-fill selection icon all the way down to cell `C20` and all of those cells will correctly calculate the drop-down list based on the available Clusters and IDs.

Comment: Waw ... Thank you so much for the elaborative prompt response (very much appreciated) ... the challenge with my sheet is that I have around 4000 clusters each having up to 10 IDs, so the UniqueClusterList area will be very hard to build entering the array formula for each cluster. Is there a workaround for the UniqueClusterList area to be built quickly.

Comment: Your other option is to create a VBA solution by coding a user defined function (UDF) that will create a range of values. That depends on how comfortable you are with coding VBA. Unless other folks smarter than me can jump in, this is how I would create the `UniqueClusterList`. Excel can support up to 16,535 columns.

Comment: Appreciate your swift and kind response :) Will try my luck with VBA.